# Flask shared state between threads and requests

Tags: python, flask

In my flask app I'm trying to create a global cache to store workers created by each request. I want to know when there are multiple threads running my flask app, is this cache accessible to all threads, or does each thread retain its own cache?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json import jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

cache = {}

class WorkerClass():
  def __init__(self,uuid):
    self.uuid=uuid
    self.worker=...

 def doSomething():
    ...


@app.route("/create")
def create():
    uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    cache[uuid] = WorkerClass(uuid)
    return "worker created",200

@app.route("/run_worker/<uuid>")
def run_worker():
    if uuid nor in cache:
        return "worker not found",404
    cache[uuid].doSomething()
    return "work done",200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this your sample, It's `true`. The cache can be accessed by all threads that forked by many requests come. Variable `cache` is a global variable so all thread used only one cache.

In your `app.run()`, The flask app run one process. So, all request call to `/run_worker/<uuid>` will accept to same cache

Same your sample, but I run with `app.run(threaded=False, processes=1)`. Each thread of request retain its own cache

Comment: hmm is there a way to create shared cache for all threads when ``app.run(threaded=False, processes=10)``

Comment: If you want to run with many process or many worker (that deployed by gunicorn), you can use `Flask-Caching` with mode `SimpleCache`